# Arangodb update query failing with error 1213

Tags: arangodb

```
var docs = ///aql
for(var i = 0; i< docs.length;i++) {
    db._collection(edgeCol).update(docs[i]._id, {"a": 10});
}
```

I get following error:

> [ArangoError 1213: cross collection request not allowed] Error: cross collection request not allowed

Comment: Oops, my mistake. docs was having documents from other than edgeCol collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1213 (cross-collection request) means that you are calling `update` on a collection but specify the id of a document from another collection for update. This is unsupported.

What you could do instead is either update by `_key`, i.e.

```
for(var i = 0; i< docs.length;i++) {
    db._collection(edgeCol).update(docs[i]._id, {"a": 10});
}
```

or update using the `db` object and its `_update` method (and omitting the collection object):

```
for(var i = 0; i< docs.length;i++) {
    db._update(docs[i]._id, {"a": 10});
}
```